# Child class calls a method of the parent class

Tags: objective-c, methods, parent-child, class-hierarchy, alloc

In objective-C I want to have a child class call or invoke a parent's method. As in the parent has allocated the child and the child does something that would invoke a parent method. like so:

```
//in the parent class
childObject *newChild = [[childClass alloc] init];
[newChild doStuff];

//in the child class
-(void)doStuff {
    if (something happened) {
        [parent respond];
    }
}
```

How could I go about doing this? (if you could explain thoroughly I would appreciate it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOWTO access the method declared in the parent class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063484/howto-access-the-method-declared-in-the-parent-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a delegate for this: have childClass define a delegate protocol and a delegate property that conforms to that protocol. Then your example would change to something like this:

```
// in the parent class
childObject *newChild = [[childClass alloc] init];
newChild.delegate = self;
[newChild doStuff];

// in the child class
-(void)doStuff {
    if (something happened) {
        [self.delegate respond];
    }
}
```

There's an example of how to declare and use a delegate protocol here: [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers/6169104#6169104)

Answer (score 4):

There's not really a lot to explain.

For use in this situation you have the keyword `super`, which is a lot like `self`, except that it refers to what `self` had been had it been a member of its own immediate superclass:

```
// in the child class
- (void)doStuff {
  if (something happened) {
    [super respond];
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not right - `super` refers to an object's superclass, not the object that instantiated it.

Comment: @Simon Whitaker: He is asking about a *child class*. Not the correct terminology, sure, but it's a leap to suggest he wants to talk to the instantiating object.

Comment: Not really - that's exactly what he specifies in his question. "The parent has allocated the child and the child does something that would invoke a parent method." Agree that the terminology's poorly used though.

Comment: @Simon Whitaker: That sentence could equally well refer to subclassing and delegation.

Comment: Actually I want the instantiating object. I don't know what the "correct" terminology would be for an object that allocates another.

Comment: This answer is great if you just foget `super` keyword in Obj-C. I found this question/answer in Google, and this is what I actually looked for. Thank you.