# How to access first class method from second class in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written two classes which contains same method (print). I want to access first class print method using second class object. How i can achieve this?

Code:

```
@interface classA : NSObject
-(void) print;
@end

@implementation classA

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"hello");
}

@end

@interface classB : classA

-(void) print;
@end

@implementation classB

-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"hey");
}
@end
```

Now i created second class object like

```
classB *B = [classB alloc]init];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063484/howto-access-the-method-declared-in-the-parent-class

Comment: I got the answer from this stack overflow link. Thanks ilight.

Comment: Also you should capitalise your class names i.e. ClassB

Comment: Try delegated functionality to call the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use delegates to access other classes
[@protocol](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/simple-objective-c-protocol-example/)

Comment: How can we achieve this using @protocol? I am new to objective c... please suggest in this regard.

Comment: google "objective c delegate pattern" and there's thousands of results with good examples. Here's the first: http://enroyed.com/ios/delegation-pattern-in-objective-c-and-writing-custom-delegates/

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this way also

```
@implementation view1
(void)someMethod
{
   ......code of method...
}

@implementation view2
(void)fistMethod
{
    view1 *abc = [[view1 alloc]init];
    [abc someMethod];
    [abc release];
}
```

also check this [Objective-C call function on another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448/objective-c-call-function-on-another-class)