# How do you use string with one class in another class on iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring

I need help. I have a view with a `tableView`, when I click a cell, it shows me the other view with a `mapView`. How do you use a string with one class in another class?

Comment: see this - [iOS - Passing variable to view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272864/ios-passing-variable-to-view-controller/11274661#11274661)

Comment: see this question:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245100/how-to-access-first-class-method-from-second-class-in-objective-c/13245178#13245178

Comment: I did so, but it does not work: (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please write in  map view controller**

**in .h file of Map view controller**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* strToSend;
```

**in .m file of Map view controller**

```
@synthesis strToSend;
```

**in base viewController where TableView is programmed**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     MapView* mapObj = [[MapView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
     mapObj.strToSend = @"Text To Send"; // you can send  string to MapView controller via this string object 
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapObj animated:YES];
     [mapObj release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `@Property (nonatomaic,retain) NSString *stringToshow;` in next view and assign its value in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate of `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way yo do this task

**1. By using getter and setter property(making @property()).**
**2. Using `NSUserDefault`**

Just follow my answer to get Better result

[passing the value from one class to other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602840/passing-the-value-from-one-class-to-other-class/13606108#13606108)